# Chromium: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, chromium, ubuntu-16.04

For some reason, whenever I try connecting to certain webpages (ex. YouTube), Chromium always returns an error that says "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

I've tried switching over to other browsers (Tor, Firefox, Vivaldi, and Opera), none of which work. Interestingly, I can access it from other devices on my network (my phone, for example) or when I boot into Windows 10 rather than Ubuntu, so it can't be a modem/router or ISP issue. Additionally, I'm able to access webpages like https://www.youtube.com but not http://www.youtube.com.

This happens pretty much at random - there's no list of sites that work and do not work.

What could be causing this?

**EDIT**: Another error has popped up - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. This occurs in addition to the original ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED issue.

**EDIT 2**: Updated to Ubuntu 16.04, but nothing has changed. I still get the same errors.

[image: Proxy settings]
[image: iptables]

Comment: Seems like you might have a proxy server defined for http traffic?

Comment: I don't think so. I haven't changed any network configurations in the past 2 months and it only started last week.

Comment: Did you check your proxy settings?

Comment: According to these settings, I don't have a proxy set up, but I'm not sure this is the only proxy configuration dialog. http://i.imgur.com/pvGYXgZ.png

Comment: Could you add an `sudo iptables -L` to the question?  The proxy stuff looks right, so we need to find out what is issuing the RST packet.

Comment: Here's what I got: http://i.imgur.com/RvrTcws.png

Comment: And what is the IP address of your ubuntu box?

Comment: The internal IP address is 192.168.1.137; not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: Do you know why you have those rules in iptables?  Do you have rules in `iptables --table nat --list` as well?

Comment: Just ran `iptables --table nat --list` and this is what I got: http://i.imgur.com/dljm0jd.png

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about this thread, but it seems like the thing that was causing these errors was that my router was blocking access to this sites (I'm not sure why) and therefore disallowed any requests to go through. HTTPS connections worked because the HTTPS URLs weren't disallowed, just the regular, unsecured ones. Removing the access block restored access to these sites.

Still not exactly sure how I was able to access these sites with another device; could be some sort of caching going on.